# Angular 6 how to pipe http call

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a HTTP service, which uses HttpClient to make API calls:

```
//provider.service.ts
export interface Lesson {
    id?: number,
    name: string,
    type: LessonType,
    teacher_data: string,
    student_data: string
}

export class ProviderService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    postLesson(form): Observable<Lesson> {        
        const body = this.getFormUrlEncoded(form.value);
        return this.http.post<Lesson>('/api/lesson/', body, this.postHttpOptions);
    }
}
```

And I have a component that uses this ProviderService, like this:

```
onSubmit():void {
    this.providerService.createLesson(lessonForm).subscribe(result=> {
        console.log(result);
        //do my stuff
      });
    }
  }
```

It works fine, everything is good. Now I want to make a LessonService, to make all http calls go through that service. It is going to cache results, emit on changes, etc.

I wrote it in this way:

```
//updated lessons.component.ts
    onSubmit():void {
        this.LessonsService.createLesson(this.lessonForm).subscribe(result=> {
            console.log(result);
            //do my stuff
        });
    }

//lessons.service.ts
export class LessonsService {
    constructor(private http: ProviderService) {}

    @Output() lessonChange: EventEmitter<Lesson> = new EventEmitter();

    public createLesson(form): Observable<Lesson> {
        let observable = this.http.postLesson(form);
        observable.pipe(
            map(result => {
                //this code is not executed, I do not understand why                
                this.lessonChange.emit(result);
                return result;
            })
        );    
        return observable;
  }
}
```

I want to emit an event when I get the result from my HTTP provider. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways you can do this, one is putting the `pipe` in the variable declaration and using `tap` instead of `map`.

```
export class LessonsService {
    @Output() lessonChange: EventEmitter<Lesson> = new EventEmitter();

    public createLesson(form): Observable<Lesson> {
        let observable = this.http.postLesson(form).pipe(
            tap(result => {
                //this code is not executed, I do not understand why                
                this.lessonChange.emit(result);
                return result;
            })
        );    
        return observable;
  }
}
```

Another way, would be to create a subscription to the variable

```
export class LessonsService {
    @Output() lessonChange: EventEmitter<Lesson> = new EventEmitter();

    public createLesson(form): Observable<Lesson> {
        let observable = this.http.postLesson(form);
        observable.subscribe(result => {
            //this code is not executed, I do not understand why                
            this.lessonChange.emit(result);
            return result;
        );    
        return observable;
  }
}
```

I would personally go for the latter, this way you can ensure that the event is only emitted on success.

Comment: In the second approach, there will be 2 http calls, won't it?
First will be executed, when component subscribes, and the second in service

Comment: @RustamGaneyev that could happen, but if you're using a library like Angular, this is the best way to do so.